# How to manually invoke jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

My html page loads beautifully, but I have some JavaScript that adds a few buttons.  jQuery Mobile doesn't style the newly created buttons.

Q: How can I run jQuery Mobile again so that the newly created buttons are styled according to the data-theme attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> **Enhancing new markup** 
> The page plugin dispatches a pagecreate event, which most widgets use to auto-initialize themselves. As long
>   as a widget plugin script is referenced, it will automatically enhance
>   any instances of the widgets it finds on the page.
>
> However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via
>   Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to
>   handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within
>   the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page
>   div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin
>   (listview button, select, etc.).
>
> For example, if a block of HTML markup (say a login form) was loaded
>   in through Ajax, trigger the create event to automatically transform
>   all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this case) into the
>   enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:

```
$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
```

> **Create vs. refresh: An important distinction** 
> Note that there is an important difference between the create event and refresh method that
>   some widgets have. The create event is suited for enhancing raw markup
>   that contains one or more widgets. The refresh method should be used
>   on existing (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated
>   programmatically and need the UI be updated to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with `data-role=listview` attribute after page
>   creation, triggering create on a parent element of that list would
>   transform it into a listview styled widget. If more list items were
>   then programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method
>   would update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave
>   the existing list items untouched.

Comment: Uh oh, I just noticed I'm overusing a certain adjective.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `.button()` function which you can pass the `refresh` string to refresh button widgets:

```
$('#my-new-button').button();//this will create a button

$('#my-old-button').button('refresh');//this will refresh a button
```

Phill shows an example of using `.trigger('create')` which is the same as `.button()` for a button widget. Each widget has a function you can call. `Listview`s use the `.listview()` function, etc.

Comment: So I could create the button and then append it to whatever I wanted to append it to.  Nice!